# Error when using multidimensional-array of 0 length

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to use two-dimension array inside of some struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    another_struct *array[][];
}some_struct;
```

But seems i can't do multidimensional array of incomplete type, so i choose to go with `another_struct *array[0][0];`

And allocate it this way:

```
some_struct *allocate_some_struct(int rows, int cols){
    some_struct *p;
    uint32_t length;

    length = sizeof(some_struct) + rows * sizeof(another_struct *[cols]);
    p = malloc(length);
    p->rows = rows;
    p->cols = cols;
    return (p);
}
```

But whenever i try to access it this way : `((another_struct *[p->rows][p->cols])p->array)[i]`,i get this `error: used type 'another_struct *[p->rows][p->cols]' where arithmetic or pointer type is required`.

Although `(*((another_struct *(*)[p->rows][p-cols])&(p->array)))[i]`, work perfectly fine. 
So my questions is why can't i use first syntax? Is there fundamental difference with the second one ?

Comment: How does the compiler know the arrangement of the elements of your array, since it has no idea the number of rows or columns, in either the code that doesn't work or the code that "work perfectly fine"?

Comment: Well maybe i should add than `p->rows = rows;` and `p->cols = cols;`, which seems to let the compiler know the number of rows and columns when casting. edit done

Comment: Maybe you don't need to specify a 2 dimensional array explicitly in the structure `another_struct *array[][]`. You could simply declare a pointer and store data on the free store if you don't mind; the pointer points to a memory that holds the data you need in the form you need (a 2 dimensional array can be seen as an array of array).

Comment: You need to declare it and allocate it as a 1-dimensional array and work out the 1-dimensional index corresponding to your 2-dimensional indices. E.g. `p->array[r * p->cols + c]`.

Comment: if you want to dynamic 2D array use `another_struct **array;`

Comment: @IanAbbott I would prefere to use the 2-dim syntax but your way works as well. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

In C typing is static, so it means that every type must be completely known when you operate with it (when compiling has finished).  For a bidimensional array, this means that all the dimensions must be know for the language to be able to do the access to the individual cells.  Access to an array is made using a formula that need the size of the already used indexed parts of it.  For a cell is the cell size, but for an array of cells you must know how many cells you have in that direction.

But, there's a workaround that allows you to use indexing with the `[]` brackets, and doesn't need to know any size but the size of an individual cell.  You have to use pointers, as in this example:

```
double **new_matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    double **res = malloc(rows * sizeof(double *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        res[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(double));
    return res;
}
void free_matrix(double **matrix, int rows)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
}
...
double **matrix = new_matrix(24, 3);
matrix[12][1] /* will access correctly row 13 and column 2 element */
...
free(matrix, 24); /* will free all allocated memory */
```

There are solutions that allow you to allocate the whole matrix (and the pointers in one bunch (and allow to use `free(3)` directly on the matrix thing) but I leave this as an exercise to the reader :)